# ord() python function that returns constaint lenght

Tags: python, ascii

I am currently writing a program in which I need to convert a text file from ascii to integer and after doing some operations convert back.  However the problem is that ord() can return anywhere from a 1 to 3 digit number and it would be really nice if it could return a standard number of digits.  Since my programs are currently

```
def convert_message_number2ascii(mystring):
    newstring = ""
    print("number:")
    for i in range(0,len(mystring),2):
        print("mystring[i:i+2]:"+mystring[i:i+2])
        newstring = newstring + str(chr(int(mystring[i:i+2])))
        print(newstring)
    return newstring


def convert_message_ascii2number(mystring):
    newstring = ""
    print("ascii:")
    for i in range(0,len(mystring)):
        newstring = newstring + str(ord(mystring[i]))
        print(newstring)
return newstring
```

But this is not working because as I said ord returns difforent size integers is there another function that returns like 000 for ord(\0) instead of 0?  if not what is the best way to do this since I can only think of "ugly" ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string formatting to achieve this:

```
def convert_message_ascii2number(mystring):
    newstring = ""
    print("ascii:")
    for i in range(0,len(mystring)):
        newstring = newstring + "%03d" % ord(mystring[i])
        print(newstring)
    return newstring
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to take a number with 3 or fewer digits and format that number with 3 digits always, prefixing with zeroes. For example, format `5` as `005` and `50` as `050`.

You can do this with the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) method.

For example:

```py
number = 5
"{:03}".format(number) # note: the 3 means use 3 digits
```

returns

```py
"005"
```

In context:

```py
for i in range(0,len(mystring)):
    char_code = ord(mystring[i])
    formatted_char_code = "{:03}".format(char_code)
    newstring = newstring + str(formatted_char_code)
    print(newstring)
```

But if you can, maybe consider storing all these character codes in a list instead of one big string.

Comment: there is a reason that I need to have it as a string thanks.